# How to echo a string with a pipe character in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, tasklist

How can I make a text file with the given line using batch script:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" | find /i "chrome.exe"
```

I created a batch file and put this code below:

```
echo tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" | find /i "chrome.exe" >>d:\dblank.txt
```

It created a dblink.text file but when I opened the dblink.txt the only text was:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe"
```

Why didn't it copy the code:

```
| find /i "chrome.exe"
```

How can I copy the whole text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch echo pipe symbol causing unexpected behaviour](/q/1855009/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the pipe character

```
echo tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" ^| find /i "chrome.exe" >>d:\dblank.txt
```

Without this escape, is it considered a real pipe operation request, and `find` is called to filter the output of the `echo` command.